# In Android, does swapping a page from ZRAM count against Major page fault?

Tags: android, memory, kernel, swap

Android I am working on, is using ZRAM which is set as a swap device to swap pages
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/low-ram.html#zram

During memory pressure, I see major page fault count increasing (pgmajfault in /proc/vmstat)

I wanted to know if this major page fault increase, also accounts for pages swapped in and out of ZRAM? Or does this count excludes ZRAM and calculates just the swap in/out of disk (writing back file cache pages)?

If not, what tool entry/metric helps to figure out if/when ZRAM was involved?